# Use same content request google map api and get different results

Tags: python, pandas, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

These days I encounter a really weird problem and cannot solve it.Please help!
I want to use google map api to get the longitude and latitude of an address.Here is my definition of the function to request api:

```
def get_coordinates(df):
if pd.notnull(df['geocode']):
    address=df['geocode']
    response = requests.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" 
                        + address+"&key=my-key")
    json_response = response.json()

    if len(json_response['results'])==0:
        return 'None'
    else:
        coordinates=json_response['results'][0]['geometry']['location']
        latitude=coordinates['lat']
        longitude=coordinates['lng']

        l_l=[latitude, longitude]
        return l_l
else:
    return 'None'
```

I store the address in a dataframe.

[image] 

Then I can use df.apply to request api for each address:

```
test2['coor1'] = test2.apply(get_coordinates,axis = 1)
```

But then the really weird thing is: I know that most of these address should be in Brazil, but when I use scatter to plot them, I notice many of the point are out of Brazil. So I guess there is something wrong with api request.Then I run apply again and this time, some address get a totally different location from the last time. I have no idea why. I wonder if someone had the same issue before.Thanks a lot!

Comment: In Brazil there are the same street name in many municipalities. There are also same municipality name in different States. Use the complete address, and also include "Brasil" to the search string since Portugal and other portuguese speaking countries may have similar street names.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense.I have add Brazil to my address to avoid the deviation.Thanks!  But I'm still confused why I used same content to request api serval times and will get different results.Just like, I request api 2 times with the same address, first time it returns a location in USA, second time it returns a location in Brazil. Weird....